# GPS returning 0.0,0.0 as latitude and longitude on device,but working correctly on emulator

Tags: java, android, gps

I am new to android. I am able to get the GPS co-ordinates from the emulator, but getting 0.0,0.0 as latitude and longitude in my device.
here is my code. Sorry its too long..

class `GPSTracker.java`

```
package com.example.spotter;


public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude
double accuracy;

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 1 meter

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 6 * 1; // 1 sec

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", String.valueOf(latitude));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                     if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                 LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                 MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                 MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                         Log.d("Network", "Network");
                         if (locationManager != null) {
                             location = locationManager
                                     .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                             if (location != null) {
                                 latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                 longitude = location.getLongitude();
                             }
                         }
                     }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}
public double getAccuracy(){
    if(location != null){
        accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
    }

    return accuracy;

}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("spt", "in loc changed");
    /*if (MainService.loststatus > 0) {

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "http://spotter.orgfree.com/writegps.php?value="
                        + String.valueOf(this.getLatitude()) + ","
                        + String.valueOf(this.getLongitude()));
        // output is the variable you used in your program
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.d("spt", "writing coord to file");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()) + String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()),
        //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }*/

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
}
```

and `MainService.java`

```
package com.example.spotter;

public class MainService extends Service implements  Runnable {

    String str;
    Intent i1;

    static double  loststatus = 0;
    Thread t;
    //double longi,lati;
    String provider;
    Location location;
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              Intent i = new Intent();
              i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Locked.class);
              i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              startActivity(i);
              Log.d("spt", "in handler");
             }
         };


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        super.onDestroy();
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Spotter tracking service has been activated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                 "",
                 System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent i=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                         i, 0);

note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "",
     "",
     pi);
note.flags|=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;


        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
        startForeground(1337, note);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void run() {

        Looper.prepare();

        while (isMyServiceRunning()) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                Log.d("spt", "read status started");
                if ((Connectivity.isConnected(getApplicationContext()))) {
                    URL urlreadstatus = new URL("http://abc.xyz.com/status.txt");
                //  Log.d("spt",String.valueOf(URLUtil.isValidUrl("http://abc.xyz.com/status.txt")));
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(urlreadstatus.openStream()));
                    str = in.readLine();
                    if(!str.equals(null)){
                        Log.d("spt", str);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    Log.d("spt", "read status complete");
                } else {
                    Log.d("spt", "not connected");
                    break;
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.d("spt", "IO exception");
                str = "11";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(NullPointerException e){
                str="11";
            }
            if (str.equals(null)) {
                str = "11";             
            }
            if (str.length() == 1) {
                loststatus++;
                if(loststatus %10 ==0){
                    SendSms s= new SendSms();
                    Log.d("spt", "ghus gaye");
                    TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
                    String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
                    String no="15555215557";
                    if (getSimNumber != no)
                    {
                    //Log.d("spt", getSimNumber);
                        Log.d("spt", "ghus gaye dobara");

                    sendSMS();
                    }

                }

                GPSTracker gps=new GPSTracker(MainService.this);
                Log.d("spt", "lost status1 requesting location updates");
                Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()) + String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(loststatus==1){
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);  
                }
                if (loststatus > 0) {

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://abc.xyz.com/writegps.php?value="
                                    + String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()) + ","
                                    + String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()));
                    HttpPost httpPost2 = new HttpPost(
                            "http://abc.xyz.com/writeaccuracy.php?value="
                                    + String.valueOf(gps.getAccuracy()));

                    // output is the variable you used in your program
                    try {
                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        httpClient.execute(httpPost2);
                        Log.d("spt", "writing coord to file");
                        //gps.stopUsingGPS();

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }




            } else {
                loststatus = 0;
            }

        }

    }
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if ("com.example.spotter.MainService".equals(service.service
                    .getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void sendSMS() {
        String phoneNumber = "15555215556";
       GPSTracker gps=new GPSTracker(MainService.this);

        String message =String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude());

        Log.d("spt", "in send sms");

       // SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        //smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }

}
```

Please help.

Comment: Is GPS enabled on the device? Does it have a good view of the sky?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> Have you added this permission in manifest?

Comment: permissions have been added @ZohraKhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several logic problems in your code

1. In `if (isGPSEnabled)`, you are first asking for a current location and then checking if any old location is present. Same is the case in `if (isNetworkEnabled)`.
2. Request for a new location takes some time few seconds to 20 minutes. So all the further steps should done in `onLocationChanged()` which you have left empty.
3. Since you are also asking for old location, chances are that somehow an old location bearing **0.0.0.0** is stored somewhere on your device which is giving you the false value.
4. Also you have not specified if you are asking for the required permission for using GPS properly.

**update :-**
As told by OP the problem was not a clear cell reception. Once under clear sky, he got correct GPS readings.

Comment: I have also tried `onLocationChanged()` function but still the problem remains.

Comment: please show us the permissions that you are asking for getting location. Also if possible, try running your app on other android device or use any other location app such as google maps on your device to check if you are getting a location.

Comment: remove the above comment update your question with the following permissions. Also the permission you are asking is ok, so no problem there.

Comment: Got my problem solved.Thanks a lot @maths,@Rohan-Kandwal.It was due to bad GPS reception. it is working fine in the open.