# Get current latitude and longitude android

Tags: java, android, gps, geolocation, location

**Requirement**:

1.Sometimes(not everytime) I am getting latitude and longitude 0.0.

2.I want to know how to get the location update after user has enabled the gps from the settings.

Here is my code

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

From my activity class I am calling like this

```
 gps = new GPSTracker(this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            // \n is for new line
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
```

Comment: try - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237729/how-to-get-initial-location-with-locationmanager/30237809#30237809

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265590/gps-returning-0-0-0-0-as-latitude-and-longitude-on-device-but-working-correctly

Comment: @Amsheer how the link helps me to fulfil my both requirements?

Comment: @Logic how does the link defers from the code I am using.Can you explain me more please.

Comment: @Soham That link list out the reasons of getting 0.0. "I am getting latitude and longitude 0.0."

Comment: @Amsheer.Thanks .But how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using Emulator ?

Comment: Nope.I am using phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you're using is just broken.  It should never be used.  The behavior you're seeing is one of the bugs-  it doesn't handle the case of getLastLocation returning null, an expected failure.  It was written by someone who kind of knew what he was doing, but it got highly upvoted several years ago and screws people up to this day.

Answer (score 3):

Don,t Forget to put service in manifest file

```
<service
        android:name"your package name.GPSTracker"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
```

[link for Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29035546/4990308), try this link

Answer (score 2):

I created a tutorial to get the current latitude and longitude using location manager.Download source code here ([Get Current Location Using Background Service](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/service-in-android/))

**MainActivity.java**

```
 package servicetutorial.service;

import android.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.renderscript.Double2;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn_start;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;
boolean boolean_permission;
TextView tv_latitude, tv_longitude, tv_address,tv_area,tv_locality;
SharedPreferences mPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor medit;
Double latitude,longitude;
Geocoder geocoder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    tv_address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    tv_latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);
    tv_longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);
    tv_area = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_area);
    tv_locality = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_locality);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    medit = mPref.edit();


    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (boolean_permission) {

                if (mPref.getString("service", "").matches("")) {
                    medit.putString("service", "service").commit();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleService.class);
                    startService(intent);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enable the gps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    fn_permission();
}

private void fn_permission() {
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))) {


        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

                    },
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

        }
    } else {
        boolean_permission = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                boolean_permission = true;

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        latitude = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("latutide"));
        longitude = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("longitude"));

        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

            tv_area.setText(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
            tv_locality.setText(stateName);
            tv_address.setText(countryName);



        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        tv_latitude.setText(latitude+"");
        tv_longitude.setText(longitude+"");
        tv_address.getText();


    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(GoogleService.str_receiver));

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}


}
```

**GoogleService.java**

```
package servicetutorial.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
```

* Created by deepshikha on 24/11/16.
     */

```
public class GoogleService extends Service implements LocationListener{

boolean isGPSEnable = false;
boolean isNetworkEnable = false;
double latitude,longitude;
LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Timer mTimer = null;
long notify_interval = 1000;
public static String str_receiver = "servicetutorial.service.receiver";
Intent intent;




public GoogleService() {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(),5,notify_interval);
    intent = new Intent(str_receiver);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

private void fn_getlocation(){
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable){

    }else {

        if (isNetworkEnable){
            location = null;
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,0,this);
            if (locationManager!=null){
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location!=null){

                    Log.e("latitude",location.getLatitude()+"");
                    Log.e("longitude",location.getLongitude()+"");

                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    fn_update(location);
                }
            }

        }


        if (isGPSEnable){
            location = null;
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,0,this);
            if (locationManager!=null){
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (location!=null){
                    Log.e("latitude",location.getLatitude()+"");
                    Log.e("longitude",location.getLongitude()+"");
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    fn_update(location);
                }
            }
        }


    }

}

private class TimerTaskToGetLocation extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fn_getlocation();
            }
        });

    }
}

private void fn_update(Location location){

    intent.putExtra("latutide",location.getLatitude()+"");
    intent.putExtra("longitude",location.getLongitude()+"");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found very simple and smooth solution :
follow this steps to get your current location , it's **very easy** don't worry i have **tested** it and working **perfectly**

1. Add dependency in build.gradle

> implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"

1. Add those 2 permissions in manifest file

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   ```
2. Add this snipt to your class MainActivity:

   public class MainActivity extends Activity **implements LocationListener** {

   ```
   LocationManager locationManager;
   String provider;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
               Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           // Check Permissions Now
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                   new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                   0);
       }
       // Getting LocationManager object
       statusCheck();

       locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(
               Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

       // Creating an empty criteria object
       Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

       // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
       provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

       if (provider != null && !provider.equals("")) {
           if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
               final Intent poke = new Intent();
               poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                       "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
               poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
               poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
               sendBroadcast(poke);
           }
           // Get the location from the given provider
           Location location = locationManager
                   .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                   LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500, 0, this);

           if (location != null)
               onLocationChanged(location);
           else
               location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
           if (location != null)
               onLocationChanged(location);
           else

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       } else {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }

   public void statusCheck() {
       final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(
               Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

       if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
           buildAlertMessageNoGps();

       }
   }

   private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
       final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       builder.setMessage(
               "Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
               .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
                       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                   final int id) {
                               startActivity(new Intent(
                                       android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                           }
                       })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                           final int id) {
                       dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
       final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
       alert.show();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       /* getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); */
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
       TextView tvLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);

       // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
       TextView tvLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

       // Setting Current Longitude
       tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

       // Setting Current Latitude
       tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude());
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
               Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           // Check Permissions Now
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                   new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                   0);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
   ```

   }
3. Add this to your activity_main.xml

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_location"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:text="current location"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_longitude"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_latitude"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/tv_longitude"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
   ```

Comment: Doesn't work at all, has too many errors as well